# Event on task completion?

Tags: trigger, lightning, workflow

I am wondering if there is any way to fire an event (like popping up a form) on task complete. I know we an do custom buttons and what not to accomplish this, but i specifically would like to put this event on the checkbox that's shows next to tasks on leads so that we don't need to have users actually open up the task to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked into using Flow to do this?

Comment: There's (at least) one way, but it's complicated and involves a trigger, a Platform Event, and a receiving Lightning component in the utility bar (e.g. https://andyinthecloud.com/2018/02/25/user-notifications-with-utility-bar-api/)